# createEffect logs reactive updated signal, though dom is not updated with the reactive property

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I think this time I've reproduced my issue here. I am using this `create_delayed` function from previous question, now the `createEffect` in `elevate` function logs the updated value as 101. But it's not updated on the dom result.

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { For, createSignal, createMemo, mapArray, createEffect } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const _pov = createSignal({});

  const m_showdown = createMemo(() => read(_pov).showdown)

  const m_showdown_hands = createMemo(() => m_showdown()?.hands)

  let m_showdown_hand2 = create_delayed(m_showdown_hands, () => m_showdown() ? 1000 : undefined)

  let m_show_hand2 = () => m_showdown_hand2()?.map((_) => make_card(_))

  createEffect(() => {
    let res = m_show_hand2()
    if (res && res[0]) {
      res[0].elevate()
    }
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    owrite(_pov, {
      showdown: {
        hands: [1,2,3]
      }
    })
  }, 1000)

  return (
    <For each={m_show_hand2()}>{hand => 
      <span>{hand.y}</span>
    }</For>
  );
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app"));

function make_card(y) {
  let counter = createSignal(y)

  // this effect runs
  createEffect(() => {
    console.log(read(counter))
  })

  return {
    y() { return read(counter) },
    elevate() { owrite(counter, _ => _ + 100) }
  }
}

function owrite(signal, fn) {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    return signal[1](fn)
  } else {
    signal[1](_ => fn)
  }
}

function read(signal) {
  if (Array.isArray(signal)) {
    return signal[0]()
  } else {
    return signal()
  }
}

function create_delayed<T>(accessor: () => T | undefined, delay: () => number) {

  const _delayed = createSignal(accessor())

  let i_timeout

  createEffect(() => {
    accessor()
    let res = delay()

    clearTimeout(i_timeout)
    if (res !== undefined) {
      i_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        owrite(_delayed, accessor())
      }, res)
    } else {
      owrite(_delayed, undefined)
    }
  })

  return () => read(_delayed)
}
```

Comment: https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=365404012&version=1.3.16

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, the playground example seams to just work after uncommenting. It shows "33 44 2 3", which is expected, right?

Comment: Edited version https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=1652136581&version=1.3.16

Comment: Could you provide a simpler reproduction? I have very hard time deciphering exactly what is happening...
One thing I've noticed though, is that the "m_show_hand2" isn't wrapped in createMemo, so it creates a completely different array instance, every time it is called called. And it is called twice.

Comment: Thanks, it was lack of `createMemo`, It is fixed now.